# How to choose parameters for adaptive binarization automatically?

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, threshold, adaptive-threshold

I am using the function

```
cv :: adaptiveThreshold (InputArray src,
OutputArray dst,
double maxValue,
int adaptiveMethod,
int thresholdType,
int blockSize,
double C
)
```

I have to set the blockSize and C values ​​manually. But each image needs unique values. Is it possible to calculate blockSize and C in some way? Or maybe there are similar functions where the parameters are selected automatically?

Comment: pictures please?

Comment: The answer is essentially no, because the block size depends on the size of the features you are interested in. Even using advanced semantic segmentation or similar AI miracles, nobody can guess you application.